# Trying to move this logo to the right of the page

Tags: graphics, exam

Firstly, I apologise in advance if this is a really silly and obvious one.

I am trying to add a logo to the right side of every single page. I am not sure why this image is constantly showing in the middle? The original document is super messy so here is the important bit of the latex code.

Thank you so much for the help.

```
    \documentclass{exam}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 11in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}


\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  color=black,
  opacity=1,
  angle=0,
  position=current page.south,
  vshift=60pt,
  hshift=30pt,
  contents={%
  \tiny%\sffamily%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt,keepaspectratio, right]{Images/1.png}
  }
}

\begin{document}
What
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Package xkeyval Error: `right' undefined in families `Gin'` --- you have an error, don't trust the produced PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. remove `right` from `\includegraphics`
2. put `south east` instead of `south`
3. adjust `vshift` and `hshift` as you please (`hshift` with negative value).

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 11in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}


\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  color=black,
  opacity=1,
  angle=0,
  position=current page.south east,
  vshift=60pt,
  hshift=-30pt,
  contents={%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt,keepaspectratio]{Images/1.png}
  }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, you can use `nodeanchor=south east` to select the anchor of the surrounding node to align the picture.